# Trace/ Track Yii Error Information And Store It In Database

Tags: php, error-handling, yii

I'm working on my college project, I just want to track the error and its information. The error info should get stored in the database with the users source device info (for source device detection I'm using MobileDetect extension). I just want to know where should I write the code so that I can get all error information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up [log message routing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing) so that the errors get logged into your database. To do that, add an appropriately configured [`CDbLogRoute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbLogRoute) to your application configuration.

Comment: Thanks Jon, It's actually doesn't solve my problem, but it gave me an idea. thanks again.